# Can i get rid of the 'default' site in multisite?

Tags: multi-sites

I have a multisite (sub directory style), and am wondering if i can delete the default site (sites/default)? I just want to get a 404 if the site doesn't exist, no fallback.

Answer (score 2):

You can leave the default directory in place. Just make sure there is no **settings.php** file in the default directory, and only the **sites/www.yoursite.com directories** will be accessed.

When you upgrade core, the default directory will always be replaced and will receive a new copy of default.settings.php, so it makes no sense to delete it.

Comment: that works, but now when i go there i get the install page, how can i avoid this then?